# AdMob shows banner on emulator, not shows on device

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

Admob shows test banner on emulator, logcat form emulator:

```
     05-03 08:07:44.032 798-798/ru.xxx.xxx I/Ads: Starting ad request.
05-03 08:07:45.572 798-798/ru.xxx.xxx W/Ads: Loading already in progress, saving this object for future refreshes.
05-03 08:07:58.812 798-798/ru.xxx.xxx I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
05-03 08:07:58.922 798-798/ru.xxx.xxx I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
```

but when I run app on device, admob not shows test and real banner. logcat from real device:

```
    05-03 13:17:23.388 28142-28142/ru.xxx.xxx I/Ads: Starting ad request.
05-03 13:17:23.983 28142-28142/ru.xxx.xxx W/Ads: Loading already in progress, saving this object for future refreshes.
05-03 13:17:34.748 28142-28247/ru.xxx.xxx W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
05-03 13:17:34.749 28142-28142/ru.xxx.xxx W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

main activity:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdsController {


private static final String BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID = "xxx";
AdView bannerAd;
InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    // Create a gameView and a bannerAd AdView
    View gameView = initializeForView(new RunawayCat(this), config);
    setupAds();

    // Define the layout
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.addView(gameView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    layout.addView(bannerAd, params);

    setContentView(layout);


}


public void setupAds() {
    bannerAd = new AdView(this);
    bannerAd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    
    bannerAd.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID);
    bannerAd.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    AdRequest ad = builder.build();
    builder.addTestDevice("xxxx");
    bannerAd.loadAd(ad);
}


@Override
public void showBannerAd() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bannerAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            AdRequest ad = builder.build();
            bannerAd.loadAd(ad);
        }
    });


}
}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.romavaleev.runawaycat"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application


        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

admob account is not banned, i tested on 3 devices.permissions in manifest is right

Comment: Do you have an adblocker in your device?

Comment: no, clean android. 4.1.1, 4.4 and 5

Comment: the phone have an active internet access?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `builder.addTestDevice("xxxx")`

Somthing like this

```
AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
AdRequest ad = builder.build();
bannerAd.loadAd(ad);
```

I integrate Ads everyday and I have never needed to add the test device, it always shows test ads if you use a test id for Ads

You can use this test banner id

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
```

and replace this id when you will generate your final `APK`

Comment: not work( i used that id from google ads manual... information for the addTestDevice()  thanks! `05-04 13:43:56.164 20767-20767/ru.romavaleev.runawaycat I/Ads: Starting ad request.
05-04 13:43:56.916 20767-20767/ru.romavaleev.runawaycat W/Ads: Loading already in progress, saving this object for future refreshes.
05-04 13:44:08.829 20767-20778/ru.romavaleev.runawaycat W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
05-04 13:44:08.843 20767-20767/ru.romavaleev.runawaycat W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
`

Comment: well it works for me always , check internet connection of your phone if its working properly

Comment: internet connection i used different. 3G and wi-fi. i added manifest file in header, may be it wrong? version GPS 8.4.0

Comment: add this permission too `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: I tried to remove the Google account and start the app. banner loaded! in what could be a problem for my account?

Comment: ads has nothing to do with your google account on mobile

Comment: I suspect that it was necessary to clean the data of Google services. I check this conjecture in other devices

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. It could be you're assigning the testDevice *after* building the ad?

```
AdRequest ad = builder.build();
builder.addTestDevice("xxxx");
```

Swtich the two lines:

```
builder.addTestDevice("xxxx");
AdRequest ad = builder.build();
```